# Flatbuffer generated files - #include import style

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Can the flatbuffer compiler generate output that uses system-style `#include`s?

```
#ifndef FLATBUFFERS_GENERATED_MYCLASS_MOBILECONFIG_H_
#define FLATBUFFERS_GENERATED_MYCLASS_MOBILECONFIG_H_

#include "flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h"
```

For use with my build system I'd prefer it if the above line read

```
#include <flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h>
```

But I don't see a flag for this anywhere.

Comment: To do that you would need to specify a flag for your compiler (`-I <path>` in GCC) or copy the file to global include directory.

Comment: Why does you build system need that? `flatbuffers.h` is not a system header, it is best kept somewhere relative to your project.